# javafx Do a http post request in webenigne

Tags: javafx

I have googled around but unfortunately I didnt find what I am looking for. For a small application I am working on, I am using a Webview. In this webview I would like to load a page where I would like to do the login - which is done using a http post request of type

--> "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary; <--

Using a HttpURLConnection I can use a DataOutputStream passing the login data to the server. But how would I do such a login with on a WebView's WebEngine??

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the page in the [WebEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) and have the user enter their login credentials and submit them just like they would in a standard browser.  The WebEngine will do the multi-part form data post the server to appropriately log the user in.

If you need to automate this process on behalf of the user (i.e. because you have authentication credentials stored elsewhere for a kind of single sign on app), then, once the engine has fully loaded the login page, you can make [webEngine.executeScript](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript%28java.lang.String%29) calls to populate the form login fields on the page and trigger the submission of the login information to the server (probably by triggering a click event on the login form submission button).

You can also use this [routine](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10444280) to execute [jQuery](http://jquery.com) on the document to do the form filling and trigger the submission if you prefer to work with that API.

Comment: thank you!!! the second part, with the automated login is what i am looking for. Now I have a Clue on what I have to work on. I will try to work it out using webEngine.executeScript.

Comment: As the link to the routine is dead nowadays, I could find these links to be valuable: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/submiting-html-forms-with-javafx-webview-2406 and also https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3077942. Hope it helps.